# Extracting values from HTML in python

Tags: python, html, beautifulsoup, python-requests

My project involves web scraping using python. In my project I need to get data about a given its registration. I have managed to get the html from the site into python but I am struggling to extract the values.
I am using this website: https://www.carcheck.co.uk/audi/N18CTN

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests

url = "https://www.carcheck.co.uk/audi/N18CTN"

r= requests.get(url)

soup = BeautifulSoup(r.text)

print(soup)
```

I need to get this information about the vehicle

```
<td>AUDI</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<th>Model</th>
<td>A3</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<th>Colour</th>
<td>Red</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<th>Year of manufacture</th>
<td>2017</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<th>Top speed</th>
<td>147 mph</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<th>Gearbox</th>
<td>6 speed automatic</td>
```

How would I go about doing this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this example to get you started how to get information from this page:

```py
import requests
import pandas as pd
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

url = 'https://www.carcheck.co.uk/audi/N18CTN'
soup = BeautifulSoup(requests.get(url).content, 'html.parser')

all_data = []
for row in soup.select('tr:has(th):has(td):not(:has(table))'):
    header = row.find_previous('h1').text.strip()
    title = row.th.text.strip()
    text = row.td.text.strip()
    all_data.append((header, title, text))

df = pd.DataFrame(all_data, columns = ['Header', 'Title', 'Value'])
print(df.head(20).to_markdown(index=False))
```

Prints:

| Header | Title | Value |
| --- | --- | --- |
| General information | Make | AUDI |
| General information | Model | A3 |
| General information | Colour | Red |
| General information | Year of manufacture | 2017 |
| General information | Top speed | 147 mph |
| General information | Gearbox | 6 speed automatic |
| Engine & fuel consumption | Power | 135 kW / 184 HP |
| Engine & fuel consumption | Engine capacity | 1.968 cc |
| Engine & fuel consumption | Cylinders | 4 |
| Engine & fuel consumption | Fuel type | Diesel |
| Engine & fuel consumption | Consumption city | 42.0 mpg |
| Engine & fuel consumption | Consumption extra urban | 52.3 mpg |
| Engine & fuel consumption | Consumption combined | 48.0 mpg |
| Engine & fuel consumption | CO2 emission | 129 g/km |
| Engine & fuel consumption | CO2 label | D |
| MOT history | MOT expiry date | 2023-10-27 |
| MOT history | MOT pass rate | 83 % |
| MOT history | MOT passed | 5 |
| MOT history | Failed MOT tests | 1 |
| MOT history | Total advice items | 11 |

Answer (score 2):

Since you don't have extensive experience with BeautifulSoup, you can effortlessly match the table containing the car information using a [CSS selector](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css_selectors.php) and then you can extract the header and data rows to combine them into a dictionary:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

url = "https://www.carcheck.co.uk/audi/N18CTN"
soup = BeautifulSoup(requests.get(url).text, "lxml")

# Select the table containing the car information using CSS selector
table = soup.select_one("div.page:nth-child(2) > div:nth-child(4) > div:nth-child(1) > table:nth-child(1)")
# Extract header rows from the table and store them in a list
headers = [th.text for th in table.select("th")]
# Extract data rows from the table and store them in a list
data = [td.text for td in table.select("td")]
# Combine header rows and data rows into a dictionary using a dict comprehension
car_info = {key: value for key, value in zip(headers, data)}

print(car_info)
```

Ouput:

```
{'Make': 'AUDI', 'Model': 'A3', 'Colour': 'Red', 'Year of manufacture': '2017', 'Top speed': '147 mph', 'Gearbox': '6 speed automatic'}
```

In order to obtain the CSS selector pattern of the table you can use the [devtools](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Web_development_tools) of your browser:

[image]